# vista bllocks my systray icon for some reason

Tags: windows-vista, systray

Why VISTA says to end-user that it has blocked my app's systray icon? how to avoid this?

Comment: What code are you using to try and add your icon to the notification area?

Comment: using the basic win32 api, app works ok with my own Win7

Answer (score 0):

Your program may not have the privileges (security settings) it needs to run.

Comment: please be more speciric what settings and where